# window blocking particles

Tags: particles

Hi ppl :) need help.

This is a window that opens and closes. I need that when the window is open the particles pass but when the window is closed the particles do not pass.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That should work just setting the window a collision object (physics panel)

Comment: Thanks now it works now. My problem was that I chose all the blades in a group and applied collision, I thought everyone would have collision and I did not work but now I did it one by one and now if it works :) thanks